# Looking for a font - random characters based on sign lettering

Tags: fonts, opentype

This is a bit of a long shot, but maybe someone here knows this. I came across this font project a few months ago that I think was based on a sign the creator kept seeing at a burger place? It was one of those marquee signs but they had used all different letters so it looked really random.

The designer had built a font inspired by that and worked with a developer to make it truly randomize which alternate was used as they typed.

Ring any bells? I can't remember how I found it the first time.

Comment: While waiting a proper answer check this old case about random fonts: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26833/handwriting-font-that-at-random-picks-characters

Comment: This is reaaally too broad... we can't just guess what you saw.

Comment: Do you mean fonts like some of these here: https://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=random&page=1

Comment: Or even some of these https://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=ransom

Answer (score 1):

Update, I found it! For anyone curious it was [Local Gothic](https://vllg.com/schwartzco/local-gothic) by Christian Schwartz and Tal Leming.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly [Carey Type](http://lestercarey.com/)? "Lester Carey was a New Orleans sign artist whose work has been found on churches, corner stores, neighborhood bars, and other commercial buildings around numerous neighborhoods of New Orleans for three decades."

Comment: Not the one I was thinking of, but a neat project. Thanks!