# InDesign plug-in for random text variations in size and position

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, plugin

I'm trying to typeset a book with an "old" / "handmade" look, with little irregularities, shuffled up kerning and spacing, letters that are slightly unaligned, and so on. More or less like [in this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/writing-text-with-character-variations), but I'm looking for a solution that does *not* rely on a custom font: is there a plug-in or a script for InDesign that randomly applies variations in size/shift/position to characters in text in order to achieve this effect?

In essence the final effect should be something like shown below (this uses the [Patina plug-in](https://www.ilcovile.it/V3_p_patina.html) for LibreOffice):
[image]

Also, [see here for a treatise](https://www.ilcovile.it/scritti/COVILE_834_Reprint_Random_Font.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an InDesign script called [Humane Type](https://www.behance.net/gallery/35895897/Humane-Type) that does something like that and allows you to tweak the parameters with a UI.

If you need something even more specific, this would require writing your own script.

Comment: Great! “Humane Type” appears to be a bit too ‘random’ in its output, but it is a great starting point. I’ll try to adapt it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is not for InDesign, however it is possible to apply the Roughen filter in Illustrator to text to give it a very slightly irregular look. Obviously you can mess around with the size and detail sliders to tweak the effect yourself.

[image]

Here's an example showing the effect being switched on and off.

[image]

Comment: Nice. So maybe a combination of the two answers would work well. First mix up, the kerning/spacing/positioning of the letters, then send the result to Illustrator to roughen up the paths.

Comment: @mdomino - sure, that sounds like a plan!